# Java change between several MouseListeners

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am working on an Drawing programm, which is using several `MouseListeners`.
For example, I hava a `class` for drawing a line with a `MouseListener` and another one for drawing a circle. I start the `MouseListener` with a `button` and then `validate()` is called.
Now I want to highlight a line or circle element, when the mouse is over the element.
But I dont want to use a `button` for it. Instead after drawing an `element` the new `Mouselistener` for highlighting should start. But I dont know how to call `validate()` then.  Or how to implement a `MouseListener` in a `non static` method.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your qustion with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated the descriptions in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `element.removeMouseListener(theListener)` and add another Listener using `element.addMouseListener(theOtheristener)`.